# how to get two fields side by side in html forms using divs

Tags: html, css

i tried creating form with fields side by side using divs .But they are diplayed one after another in rows. here i am getting batchcode and coursecode intwo rows .How to get them in a single row side by side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>

        <link href="css/reset.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/default.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="sidebarmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <script src="sidebarmenu.js"></script>
                <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script> 

</head>
    <body>  

        <!--<form id="frmExamRegistration" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="anu">-->


    <form name="f1" method="post" class="anu">  
    <%@include file="header.html"%>

<div  style="float:right;width:10%;border:0;font-color:#163362"><a href=logout.jsp">Log Out</a></div>
<%@include file="sidemenus.jsp" %>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="content"  ><center>Delete Batch</center><br>
            <div class="formElements">
                <label>Batch code:</label>
                 <span><input type="text" id="txtBatchcode" name="txtBatchcode" ></span>

            <div class="formElements" style="z-index:-1">
                <label>Course Code:</label>
                 <span><input type="text" id="txtCoursecode" name="txtCoursecode" ></span>

            <div class="buttons" align="center">
                <button type="submit" class="primaryAction">Delete</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="primaryAction">Clear</button>

            </div></div></div>
                 </div>
         </div>
       </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.com link of the code so we can play with it?

Comment: @DeadMan I hadn't tried it till now.

Comment: Just go to jsfiddle.com and put your `HTML` in the HTML section, `CSS` in the CSS section and `JS` at the JS section and from the left sidebar, just select the jquery library of your version, save it and post your `url` here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display:inline-block;` on each of the `.formElements` blocks.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/hAwyy/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">Delete Batch</h2>
        <div class="formElements" style="display:inline-block;">
            <label>Batch code:</label>
            <span><input type="text" id="txtBatchcode" name="txtBatchcode" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="formElements" style="display:inline-block;">
            <label>Course code:</label>
            <span><input type="text" id="txtCoursecode" name="txtCoursecode" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons" style="text-align:center;">
            <button type="submit" class="primaryAction">Delete</button>
            <button type="reset" class="primaryAction">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would try to avoid using inline styles. Unfortunately, I don't know the other CSS styles you have going on, and can't predict conflicts.

Comment: thanks for code.You did what exactly i need. But when i am placing it in my html its not getting like that.below is the way it is being displayed in my html

Comment: you probably have some CSS defined for your input elements...probably a display:block on either the span you have wrapping them or the input element itself.

Comment: were you able to find the extra `display:block;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : define `class` in `css` which will apply on all `.formElements`

```
<style type="text/css">
.formElements{
    display:inline;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using table:

```
 <form name="f1" method="post" class="anu">
    <div style="float:right;width:10%;border:0;font-color:#163362">
        <a href=logout.jsp ">Log Out</a></div>


    <div id="container ">
        <div class="content "  ><center>Delete Batch</center><br>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Batch code:</label> <span><input type="text " id="txtBatchcode " name="txtBatchcode " ></span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Course Code:</label> <span><input type="text " id="txtCoursecode " name="txtCoursecode " ></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XVSNc/1/)**

Using table is the easiest way. You don't have to use **CSS** at all.

Comment: its in correct format.But it is automaticaly ajusting height of the form to that row only

Answer (score 0):

see its very simple , Make your div float left .. so they will start from left and end up on full width then, they will take place in next row .

```
<div width="100%">
<div style="float:left , width :50%">your content here    </div>
<div style="float:left , width :50%">  your content here </div>
<div></div>,
</div>
```